# Laravel 5.3.6 Ajax delete gives 404 error

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, laravel-routing

Busy learning Laravel and a bit (very) confused.

I have a page with datatable and a button to delete a record.

I want this button to delete the record with ajax.

My js code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.deleteBtn', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');

    swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You will not be able to recover this business type file!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
                cancelButtonText: "No, cancel pls!",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            },
            function(isConfirm){
                if (isConfirm) {
                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });
                    $.ajax ({
                        url: url,
                        type: 'DELETE',
                        success: function () {
                            swal("Deleted!", "Your business type has been deleted.", "success");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
                }
            });

    return false;
});
```

In the Routes/api.php file:

```
// business type
Route::delete('businessTypes/{business_type_id?}/destroy', ['as' => 'businessTypes.destroy', 'uses' => 'BusinessTypeController@destroy']);
Route::any('businessType', 'ApiBusinessTypeController@businessTypeData', ['except' => ['destroy']]);
```

In Routes/web.php:

```
    Route::get('businessTypes/create', ['as' => 'businessTypes.create', 'uses' => 'BusinessTypeController@create']);
Route::get('businessTypes/{business_type_id}-{slug?}', ['as' => 'businessTypes.show', 'uses' => 'BusinessTypeController@show']);
Route::resource('businessTypes', 'BusinessTypeController', ['except' => ['show', 'create', 'destroy']]);
```

When I click the delete button I get the error: 404 Page not Found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have to set the URL to the path-> url : 'businessTypes/{business_type_id?}/destroy'

Comment: Finn, Thank you, the url path in the js file is: <a href="/businessTypes/'+row.business_type_id+'/destroy" Is that not correct?

And in the api.php it is: Route::delete('businessTypes/{business_type_id?}/destroy', ['as' => 'businessTypes.destroy', 'uses' => 'BusinessTypeController@destroy']); Still not sure what is wrong?

Comment: looks ok.  could you move the Route::delete to the web.php and check and could you please check the url right before the `$.ajax{` to see if  it is build right?

Comment: I moved the Route to the web file. The url in firebug shows: http://mysite.loca/businessTypes/1/destroy Now getting error 500, details here: http://laravel.io/bin/bE9NG

Comment: Ok, found the problem, changed my route in web to: Route::delete('/businessTypes/{business_type_id?}/destroy', ['as' => 'businessTypes.destroy', 'uses' => 'ApiBusinessTypeController@destroy']); Can you just help me and explain when do I use web.php and when api.php?

Comment: Also, looking at Laravel docs and other tutorials, I see I can do the delete directly at the route call with a function. Is it better to do it like that? e.g.:   Route::delete('/tasks/{task_id?}',function($task_id){
    $task = Task::destroy($task_id);

    return Response::json($task);
});

Comment: Depending on the the file you either apply the 'web' or the 'api' middelware from laravel check ( [Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing) and [Middelware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middelware) on the laravel site they are really well written just check. 'web wuold be what you use on your site mainly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122987/discussion-between-finn-and-sigal-zahavi).